# Benchmarking SQL Data Warehouse DWU

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm putting together some simple analysis to benchmark DWU impact on read and write based on a CTAS statement.

The query is aggregating 1.7b row table to a table of 993k rows. Source and destination tables are round-robin distribution (source won't be RR long-term, will move to HASH) the query is roughly as follows:

```
create table CTAS_My_DWU_Test 
with (distribution = round_robin) 
as
select TableKey1, TableKey2, 
SumCcolumn=SUM(SalesAmt), 
MaxQuantity=MAX(SalesQty), 
MinQuantity=MIN(SalesQty)
from FactSales
group by TableKey1, TableKey2
option (label='MyDWUTest');
```

I am analysing the performance via the sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers DMV, getting an average bytes_per_second over each distribution for both type=DIRECT_READER and type=WRITER.

My process is to change the DWU, drop the CTAS, re-create it and analyse the data in the DMV.

I'm not seeing a consistent improvement in performance as I increase the DWU. My goal is to look for clear proof of increase compute, however sometimes a higher DWU is slower and returning less bytes_per_sec than a smaller DWU.

If I happen to run the CTAS statement twice on the same DWU, without going through the scale process, the second & subsequent executions run nearly 10x faster.

Looking for help to on the process based on one table, want to keep data movement/join out of the equation for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!  The architecture of Azure SQL Data Warehouse is more performant when there is less data movement.  I recommend following the steps in this article to determine which step is slowing the process down: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor/

It's possible that your query is analyzing each of the aggregations over the 1.7b rows in serial, which doesn't maximize the parallel nature of our product, but the best way to find out what is going on is to take a look at the query plan, etc. in the link above.

As for the 10x performance on a repeat run, that's coming from internal caching in our system.

Let us know what you find in the query plan, execution plan, etc.